# Finding solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was working on this problem, to which I have the answer, but it is just that, an answer with no explanation, and I am stuck on how the answer was arrived at, for a few parts of this question.

In this question, we have the following matrix, with constants $a$ and $b$.

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -3 & 0 &3a\\
0 & 1 & b & 0 &b-4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (a-2)(b+1) &a-2\end{array} \right]$$

We are trying to find, if any, what values of $a$ and $b$ give the following:

1. No solution,
2. A unique solution,
3. A one parameter solution,
4. A two parameter solution.

I have worked out the following, which matches up with the answer given:

A1. No solution when $a \neq2$ and $b=-1$ 
A3. One parameter solution when $a \neq2$ and $b \neq-1$

But I am stuck on Q2 and Q4 and would be very grateful if someone could give me an insight into how they would tackle these parts of this question.

Thank you in advance!

PS: If you would like, I can add the answers to the remaining parts of the question, which I am stuck on. Edit: Answers, as requested: 
A2: No such $a$ and $b$.
A4: $a=2$ and b free. (I assume it means b is a parameter?)

Comment: You need to finish row reducing to obtain the RREF in order to answer the question about uniqueness.

Comment: Hint: after row-reduction, how can you tell whether the solution is unique, one-parameter, two-parameter, etc.? Specifically, in terms of pivot elements (and also, don't forget that this matrix is $3 \times 4$, which is going to be important to consider).

Comment: Also, yes, I would suggest adding the answers. This would help us in trying to explain something you are not quite seeing yet.

Comment: @crash, I don't think this is necessary; can a $4\times 3$ system **ever** have unique solutions? (i.e. can a linear map $\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ be injective?)

Comment: @BaronVT I don't think OP understands the importance of pivot positions just yet; the level of abstraction you are mentioning may be too much for OP to handle just now. But you are right that my suggestion is not *necessary*; however, pedagogically, I imagine my suggestion was what OP is meant to do.  I probably should have been more clear though.

Comment: Sure, that's fair enough, you may be correct. It may also be the case though that OP knows **if a matrix has fewer rows than columns, it cannot be injective (have unique solutions). No other investigation is necessary** already, as it is an extremely useful and pretty basic fact. Of course, we have no way of knowing if this is the case, so multiple approaches cannot hurt.

Comment: @BaronVT Unfortunately we have not done pivot elements so far. To crash: Ah that does make sense, doesnt a matrix have to be square to have any chance of being invertible? Could you explain the idea of having less rows than columns would have on the matrix BaronBT ? Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Sure thing, and thanks for clarifying. So it sounds like you already know something about what's going on ("a matrix has to be square to have any chance of being invertible"), but maybe not how to articulate the particulars. Recall (or allow me to define) $Ax = b$ is **injective** if it has unique solutions (when it has solutions, it might not), and is **surjective** if it has at least one (possibly more) solution for every $b$. A matrix that is injective and surjective is invertible, and vice-versa.

Comment: Now, if a matrix has $n$ rows and $m$ columns, you can think of it turning $m$ dimensional vectors into $n$ dimensional vectors. If $n < m$ (fewer rows) we have "more" vectors in the domain than the range, and so you would expect some of them to double up (i.e. two $n$-dim vectors map to the same target $m$-dim vector, because there aren't enough target vectors for each $n$-dim vector to have it's own *unique* target).

Comment: Likewise, if $m < n$, you're taking a smaller space ($m$ dimensional) and mapping it into a larger space ($n$ dimensional), so it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to target **every** $n$-dim vector. Thus, in this case the matrix cannot be surjective. These arguments are informal, but hopefully you see the idea. Anyway, the point is, fewer rows than columns means you cannot be injective, and fewer rows than columns means you cannot be surjective, and combined, this means a non-square matrix cannot be both injective and surjective, so it isn't invertible either.

Comment: Also, I should note that common synonyms for injective and surjective are "1 to 1" and "onto" which may sound more familiar.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, really helpful description @baronVT! One last thing, Say the matrix we were given was square. Would we find if it had a unique solution, if we let a and b be values such that we will get a leading one in each row? Thanks!

Comment: That is *close* to a correct statement, but there's enough remaining ambiguity I can't feel good about just telling you "yes". If you have a square matrix, and you fully row-reduce, you can eventually get leading $1$'s in each row. However, it is **not** necessary that, upon choosing values for $a$ and $b$, that you **immediately** have $1$, the important thing is that it is **not** zero. That is, say some leading entry is $(a - 2)(b+3)$, then any values of $a,b$ so that that entry isn't zero (say $a = 5, b = 1$) is "good for invertibility" in this sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -3 & 0 &3a\\
1 & 1 & b & 0 &b-4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (a-2)(b+1) &a-2\end{array} \right] \to
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -3 & 0 &3a\\
0 & 1 & b+3 & 0 &-3a+b-4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (a-2)(b+1) &a-2\end{array} \right]  $$

first let us look at $(a-2)(b+1)$ is zero if $a = 2$ or $b = -1.$

in the case $a = 2,$  there are infinitely many solutions. the reason is there are two free variables, third and fourth column variables.

the case $a \ne2, b = -1,$  the last equation reduces to $0 = 1$ so there are no solutions.

the remaining case $a \neq 2 \text{ and } b \neq - 1$ there is free variable, so the system has infiniteley many solutions.

Comment: Sorry @abel but i just realised I made a typo on the 1st entry of the second row. It is meant to be in fact 0 not 1. Again, my apologies. Also, if a=2, then wouldnt the 4th column be full of zeros, and then that column could not be a free variable?

Comment: lol! Typos in math...the worst. +1 for probably wanting to punch your computer in the face

Comment: even if you had all zeros in a column, that is till a free variable. the original system of equations had some non zero coefficients there.

Comment: Ah I see! We haven't learned this, but I picked up  that if there is more columns (i.e. variables) than rows (i.e. equations)  we have atleast one free variable. So, in the case of Q4 (two parameter solution), would you say that we need the above matrix, to have 2 more columns than rows? Or is this a wrong approach to take. Thanks!

Comment: number of free variables + number of pivots = total number of variables. you have two pivot variables and a total of four variables, so there are free varaibles. this gives rise to the two parameter family of infinite solutions. that you can assign any two number for the free variables and solve for the pivot variables. i am assuming that the system is consistent, that is, there are pivots on the last column of the augmented matrix.

Comment: Ah thanks for that! So for Q4, would you say to satisfy the two parameter solution, we would take the approach to get only two pivots, (since can't chain the number of variables as you have said in earlier comment), then no. of free variables = total no. of variables (4) - number of pivots (2) = 2. This can be done if we let a=2, so last row is full of zeros. Does this approach make sense? But another thing, why does the answer mention b is free? Since we have two parameter solution, shouldn't we have two variales free, not just b, or am i getting things mixed here? Thanks again!

Comment: the reason  $b$ can be arbitrary is because it comes after the pivot $1$ on the second row. and too the only the second row has $b$'s on it. the last entry on a pivot column can be anything. if you set $a = 2,$  you have a row of all zeros, so you can throw that out without affecting the solutions.